# How to share a file in device in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've created a today extension in app.sharing data using group sharing with the following code.

```
 NSUserDefaults *sharedDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.xxxxx.offline.sqlitedatabase"];
    NSString *filestirng =[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"AppointmentDB.sqlite"];
    [sharedDefaults setValue:filestirng forKey:@"filepath"];
```

I fetch this file in extension using the following code

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.xxxx.offline.sqlitedatabase"];
    NSString *string = [defaults objectForKey:@"filepath"];

     [[database sharedInstance]createtable];
     [self removeFile:@"xxxxx.sqlite"];

    NSData *dataFile = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:string];

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"xxxx.sqlite"];
    NSString* fileAtPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    [dataFile writeToFile:fileAtPath atomically:NO];
```

This code works properly on a simulator but it doesn't on a real device. I don't understand how to get the file. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

`NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` returns an URL appropriate for your current process only. You'll need to store shared data in the container of your app group.

The [containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1412643-containerurl) will give you the URL for the container of your app group.